# Javascript match issue, non-exhaustive?

Tags: javascript, regex, matching

why does `console.log("1010101".match(/101/g));` equal 2 not 3?

when there are 3 occurrences of "101"

Why is this the case?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/U17VGL/1 just look

Comment: [I get two matches only](http://rextester.com/ZDLP10811).

Answer (score 1):

That is because matched patterns are not matched anymore. You could use a positive lookahead and match only the first `1` and lookahead of the rest of the wanted pattern.

```js
console.log("1010101".match(/1(?=01)/g).length);
```

Comment: Thanks, Looking to implement it in a replace function. Will look at positive look ahead.

Comment: with this method, you match only the first `1`, not the rest. if you like to replace, then you lose the tail anway. maybe it is easier you as for a replacement with the given data and replacement string.